# Extracting specific data in a file using regex

Tags: python, regex

Following info i want to extract from a file which has different version,release date,CVE number. Can anyone show me how to retrieve that information using regex..?

```
    Release date: March 13, 2007
    Vulnerability identifier: APSB07-07
    CVE number: CVE-2007-1278
    Platform: Windows only
```

Comment: This question is incomplete/Unclear because it is missing vital components in the problem statement.  You have provided the sample input, but have not stated your exact desired output, nor have you shown your best coding attempt (or any proof of research).  Your title is also very vague and will make it hard for search engines to connect researchers needing this advice to this page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't wrap your head around regex, then don't use it. In most cases you can substitute it with regular Python string functions.

Small example for your data:

```
>>> s = """    Release date: March 13, 2007
...     Vulnerability identifier: APSB07-07
...     CVE number: CVE-2007-1278
...     Platform: Windows only"""
>>> for line in s.split("\n"):
...     if "Release date:" in line:
...         print line.split("Release date: ")[1]
...     if "CVE number:" in line:
...         print line.split("CVE number: ")[1]
... 
March 13, 2007
CVE-2007-1278
>>>
```

This can be improved ofcourse, but it's just to show you that it's quite easy without regex.

Never forget the famous quote:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think “I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

Comment: I have a file which has different platform,release date,CVE number,How can do that....?

Comment: @Kummi_10: just replace the `s` variable and `s.split("\n")` in the example with the data read from the file. Probably something like `with open("mydata.txt", "r") as infile: infile.read()`